# Getting warning while generating java doc for @RequestBody and @PathVariable in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, rest, javadoc

I am using eclipse to generate java doc for my project. Everything works fine but i get a warning when I use @RequestBody and @PathVariable in javadoc comment. How can I remove that warning to generate docs ? Following is the snippet of my javadoc:

```
   /**
     * Request POST call to create category
     * @RequestBody Category category
     * @return category id and title as JSON string
     */
```

Following warning is generated:

warning - @RequestBody is an unknown tag.

Is it okay to get such warning or do I need to do something to eliminate this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a warning because that is not valid javadoc. The valid javadoc would be

```
/**
 * Request POST call to create category
 * @param category the category to create
 * @return category id and title as JSON string
 */
```

`@RequestBody` is a Java annotation. It has nothing to do with javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Because  @RequestBody and @PathVariable are not javadoc tags.

See [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm) of javadoc tags.